# Range extremes don't seem to get drawn by random()

Tags: random, range, uniform

For several valid reasons I have to use BSD's random() to generate awfully large amounts of random numbers, and since its cycle is quite short (~2^69, if I'm not mistaken) the quality of such numbers degrades pretty quickly for my use case. I could use the rng board I have access to but it's painfully slow so I thought I could do this trick: take one number from the board, use it to seed random(), use random() to draw numbers and reseed it when the board says a new number is available. The board generates about 100 numbers per second so my guess is that random() hardly gets to cycle over and the generation rate easily keeps up with my requirements of several millions numbers per second.

Anyway, the problem is that random() claims to uniformly draw numbers between 0 and (2^31)-1, but I've been drawing an uncountable amount of numbers and I've never ever seen a 0 nor a (2^31)-1 so far. Maybe some 1 and (2^31)-2, but I've never seen the extremes. Now, I know the problem with random numbers is that you can never be sure (see Dilbert, Debian), but this seem extremely odd nonetheless. Moreover I tried analysing the generated datasets with Octave using the histc() function, and the lowest and the highest bins contain between half and three quarter the amount of numbers of the middle bins (which in turn are uniformly filled, so I guess in some sense the distribution is "uniform").

Can anybody explain this?

**EDIT** Some code

The board outputs this structure with the three components, and then I do some mumbo-jumbo combining them to produce the seed. I have no specs about this board, it's an ancient piece of hardware thrown together by a previous student some years ago, there's little documentation and this formula I'm using is one of those suggested in the docs. The STEP parameter tells me how may numbers I can draw using one seed so I can optimise performance and throttle down CPU usage at the same time.

```
float n = fabsf(fmod(sqrt(a.s1*a.s1 + a.s2*a.s2 + a.s3*a.s3), 1.0));
unsigned int seed = n * UINT32_MAX;
srandom(seed);

for(int i = 0; i < STEP; i++) {
  long r = random();
  n = (float)r / (UINT32_MAX >> 1);
  [_numbers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:n]];
}
```

Comment: `float`? Have you tried checking the raw `long`s to rule out floating point errors?

Comment: Didn't try that. I was thinking of doing it though, but if that's the case, how would you fix it? I really need the [0,1] float range.

Comment: Ok, I quickly pulled some more million numbers (...) and verified that neither 0 nor (2^31)-1 are being drawn.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that

```
void main() {
  while (random() != 0L);
}
```

hangs indefinitely? On my linux machine (the Gnu C library uses the same [linear feedback shift register](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register) as BSD, albeit with a different seeding procedure) it doesn't.

According to [this reference](http://www.newwaveinstruments.com/resources/articles/m_sequence_linear_feedback_shift_register_lfsr.htm)  the algorithm produces 'runs' of consecutive zeroes or ones up to length `n-1` where n is the size of the shift register. When this has a size of 31 integers (the default case) we  can even be *certain* that, eventually, `random()` will return 0 a whopping 30 (but never 31) times *in a row*!  Of course, we may have to wait a few centuries to see it happening...

Comment: Oddly enough (well...) it doesn't hang indefinitely. It ran for about 15 seconds before stopping. Generating a billion numbers with my code takes quite more than 15 seconds, though.

Comment: You are effectively throwing a die with two billion faces. You cannot expect to already get a zero within a few million throws!

Comment: You're obviously right but I think so far I've generated several billion numbers and getting no zeros seems quite odd. I'll keep trying, but then there's the other fact where the lowest and highest bins are never full as the others, which is likewise odd.

Comment: What bin size do you use? I cannot reproduce your results using a little [example program](http://hlub.dyndns.org/pub/Doorgeefluik/randombins.c), and find it hard to believe that BSD and GLIBC  random() behave differently in this respect.

Comment: Given I analyse with Octave, I use its linspace function to generate the bins. I usually do something like `linspace(0, 1, 50)` and change 1 to (2**31)-1 when I analyse integers instead. linspace called this way gives N evenly spaced bins in the range specified by the first two arguments.

Comment: Just to make sure: you _do_ call `srandom(seed)` with a different seed every time, don't you? What happens if you run my [example program](http://hlub.dyndns.org/pub/Doorgeefluik/randombins.c) a few times, just to make sure? It uses 64 bins (2^32 is only divisible by powers of 2) but the results should be comparable. If you still get the skewed distribution you should file a problem report with the maintainers of your C library.

Comment: Yes, I thought of the seeding problem and I positively verified that the seed is different for each call. I tried your code and yes, I still get the skewed distribution, though a little less disappointing than the one I had with my own code (that is to say the two extreme bins are fuller than mine) but still noticeably emptier than the average. I tried your code on Linux and OS X just to be sure but I get similar results. I also modified your code to reseed every once in a while but it didn't change much.

Comment: This is very strange indeed! I suppose we use, on linux at least, the same `random()` implementation. In a truly random distribution, every bin should, on average, have equally many hits, 100 in the case of my [example program](http://hlub.dyndns.org/pub/Doorgeefluik/randombins.c). Using that 10 times, I get an average of 100.4 for the first bin. What do you get?

Answer (score 0):

To extend the cycle length, one method is to run two RNGs, with different periods, and XOR their output.  See [L'Ecuyer 1988](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lecuyer/myftp/papers/cacm88.pdf) for some examples.

Comment: Even at a rate of a million `random()` calls a second, 2^69 calls will take more than a million years. If you need a cycle length that takes longer than say the age of the universe, call `initstate()` with a large enough state array.

Comment: Your comment makes sense but this is just the beginning of the story. We'll have to make several of these generators and run them in parallel to feed this giant cluster that processes them. Don't ask, I didn't either and I'm happier this way: the physics dept. is full of crazy people :) They ran these simulations and they are dead sure that in a few years (maybe one or two according to them) there are going to be "problems". We tried to tell them it doesn't make much sense but since we get part of our funding from their projects we didn't want to push that more than necessary :)